# Jena SDB support thread-safe transaction? Jena SDB error under multiple-thread execution enviroment

Tags: multithreading, jena

My code of jena is broken under the multiple-thread execution environment. I use the jena sdb to save the rdf triples. However, when i start the six threads to complete the saving data action, the exception be threw out. (every thread save a graph rdf into db,every graph is different)

I need the helps are:

**1. Whether jena SDB support the transaction, which is thread safe ?**

**2. How to implement the thread safe operation for jena sdb ?**

**3. How to solve my code problem? (The exception and key code is under below)**

So appreciate for your help and any suggestions. Wish any replay from you. Good Luck ～～

**My key code below:(Database is DB2, database pool: Websphere datasource pool)**

```
//DBConnector is an object that get the jdbc connection from the data source 
//initialize and return a sdb connection object [new SDBConnection(jdbcConnection)]
SDBConnection con = DBConnector.getSDBConnection(); 
store = SDBFactory.connectStore(con,storeDesc); 

model.notifyEvent(GraphEvent.startRead);
model.read(in,'',"N-Triple");
model.notifyEvent(GraphEvent.finishRead);
model.close();
```

**The exception is below:**

com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.LoaderTuplesNodes.Thread-6():
 Error in thread: Problem making new tupleloader

com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDBException: Problem making new tupleloader

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.LoaderTuplesNodes.updateOneTuple(LoaderTuplesNodes.java:269)

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.LoaderTuplesNodes.access$200(LoaderTuplesNodes.java:31)

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.LoaderTuplesNodes$Commiter.run(LoaderTuplesNodes.java:334)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.LoaderTuplesNodes.updateOneTuple(LoaderTuplesNodes.java:265)

... 3 more
```

Caused by: com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDBException: Problem initialising loader for [Quads]

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.TupleLoaderBase.<init>(TupleLoaderBase.java:47)

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.hash.TupleLoaderHashBase.<init>(TupleLoaderHashBase.java:17)

at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.layout2.hash.TupleLoaderHashDB2.<init>(TupleLoaderHashDB2.java:22)

... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that the store isn't being freed up after use. Could you try:

```
SDBConnection con = DBConnector.getSDBConnection(); 
store = SDBFactory.connectStore(con,storeDesc); 

model.read(in,'',"N-Triple");
store.close();
```

(The notify isn't needed)

It should be thread safe etc.

Comment: in my testing, i used the junitPref help me create the multiple-thread request. en... Maybe there are some relationship with junitPref.

Comment: i gave up use junitPref, and write the java thread by self. The exception will not be threw out. er.... It's confused to jena's thread-safe support